# Linux/C: Dynamic Memory Allocation - Tune release policy

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, glibc

My program is sometimes terminated by the kernel OOM killer, and I have some questions about the memory allocation/free in my program. First, let me describe what the program does:

- Scan a directory for all json files
- For each file:

  - Open and parse it. This is done by a library that I use as a black box
  - Parsing return a dynamically allocated data structure (likely using malloc)
  - Do some stuff with this data structure
  - Free it

I see that, at the end of the loop, my program is holding a big amount of memory (I checked it with pidstat). Trying to better understand what's going on, at each loop iteration (which means for each file), I print the currently allocated RSS memory, by reading the file `/proc/self/status` and printing the line of RSS memory.
What I see is that, when the loop meets a particularly huge json file, the memory increased a lot: this is quite obvious, because the parsing require memory, but when the data structure containing the parsed file is freed, the memory usage remains high.
I read a lot of documentation and it turned out that `free` simply mark the memory as free, but it remains binded to the process that required it and is not effectively released back to the OS. Digging further, I discovered the function [`mallopt`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html) and a set of parameters that can be set with it. These parameters allow to tune the behavior of the allocator. In particular I am playing with the parameter `M_MMAP_THRESHOLD`): the default value is 128 KB, but I see that lowering it to 104KB, calling `mallopt(M_MMAP_THRESHOLD, 104*1024)`, before the loop, I can get my program to effectively release the memory to the OS. Now my questions:

1. May this technique have any side effect to my program? (after the loop it continues with a working loop "forever")
2. The default value for the threshold is 128 KB, but the allocator has a kind of dynamic management of it, based on the statistics during execution. To stay more safe, I would like to set this working mode only during the json parsing loop, but from the documentation, looks like that once you set the parameter, the allocator definitely disable the dynamic management of the threshold. Are you aware of any way to restore the original allocator behavior after the end of the loop?

Sorry for being so long, I would like the problem is well described

Comment: Generally you don't need to worry too much about the OS reported memory usage unless it's causing a problem for you (i.e. you're getting killed by the OOM killer). Your program keeps memory after you've freed it so that it can re-use it for future allocations without needing another system call. Unless you have a strong reason not to, you can trust the allocator to choose when to release it to the OS.

Comment: (That said, I'm curious to see what suggestions people have. Good question!)

Comment: @thesecretmaster, you got the point, I'm getting OOM killer, that's why I'm analyzing the problem

Comment: It might be worth your while to analyze the program's behavior with Valgrind or a similar tool, because it sounds like you have a memory leak.  It is true that allocated memory is not necessarily released back to the system when freed, but it *does* become available for reuse to serve future allocations.  Absent memory leaks, your program should not need much more memory than it does to handle just the largest input.  If that one input requires more memory than is available, then tweaking allocator parameters is not going to solve that problem.

Comment: I run with valgrind and it reported somw definitely lost blocks. The problem is that it does not tell where this lost memory was allocated, even if I compiled with -g -O0:    

==1877== 396 bytes in 9 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 50 of 78
==1877==    at 0x4847C70: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:309)
==1877==    by 0x4B5E807: g_malloc (in /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0.6200.5)

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but I believe there's a flag that can be passed to valgrind to show that information, something like `--leak-check=full` perhaps?